# convert to decimal - input string was not correct format

Tags: c#

I have a string `"-6.379885574693132E-10"` that I can't convert to decimal..is it to big? Is it possible to work around this?

Error:

> Input string was not correct format

```
public class Program {
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        var str = "-6.379885574693132E-10";
        foo.SetPropertyValue("myVal", str);
    }
}

public class Foo {

    public decimal myVal { get; set; }

    public void SetPropertyValue(string propertyName, object value) {
        var propertyInfo = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        propertyInfo.SetValue(this,
            Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `decimal.Parse`?

Comment: Why do you need reflection at all?

Comment: @TimSchmelter This is just a small example, it's needed in my case.

Comment: @emptyman Note that `Convert.ChangeType("-6.379885574693132E-10", TypeCode.Object).GetType().FullName;` returns `System.String`. you are attempting to assign `string` to `decimal`

Comment: Your question boils down to: Why does `Convert.ChangeType("-6.379885574693132E-10", typeof(decimal), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` throw?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Well, yes it looks like it

Comment: Convert.ChangeType's job is to cast one type to another, not parse text. When converting text to a numeric type, it will use the current culture's numeric format. To parse a type, use that type's `Parse` method, if available. In this case, use `decimal.Parse`

Comment: The answer to the boiled-down question appears to be: `IConvertible` infrastructure and `Convert` static methods implicitly use `NumberStyles.Number` when converting from a `string` to a `decimal`, and your value has "scientific notation" (`E-10`) in it, so it does not conform to that. This notation is not one normally used for `decimal`, i.e. no `decimal` will have this scientific suffix in its _standard_ representation as a formatted string. **Addition:** It is the same with `Convert.ToDecimal("-6.379885574693132E-10", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` of course, it throws as well.

Comment: Is it possible to work around with reflection?

Comment: How general must your solution be. It seems that you once had a `double` which was then converted to a `string` (in that case `E` notation can occur). After that you try converting that string value directly to a third type, `decimal`. Why? You can easily hard-code the case `string` to `decimal` if you do not mind having an explicit special case in your code. But maybe you should avoid going from `double` to `decimal` via `string`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have no knowledge about reflection but you can parse this string with a combination of [`AllowDecimalPoint`, `AllowExponent` and `AllowLeadingSign` styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) with a culture that has `.` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator) like `InvariantCulture` as;

```
var s = "-6.379885574693132E-10";
var d = decimal.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | 
                         NumberStyles.AllowExponent | 
                         NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign, 
                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or more simple, you can use `NumberStyles.Float` which includes all these styles.

```
var s = "-6.379885574693132E-10";
var d = decimal.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[image]

Comment: Soner, is there a way to avoid that google shows MSDN links always in your own language("tr-tr") instead of in english("en-us")? Even if i search f.e. for `NumberStyles enumeration`(so english) i'm getting the german links. That's annoying since i always have to change "de-de" to "en-us". Do you have the same problem?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Maybe that is because your web browser sends a request where it prefers "German (Germany)" over "English (United States)" in its HTTP headers? Some web sites want to answer in the language preferred by the user. Maybe you can change some settings in your web browser?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Hmm, honestly, I never get Turkish links. You search on Google or MSDN search by the way? For example, my `CurrentCulture` setting is my local computer is `tr-TR`, I'm not logged in to MSDN with my live account, and when I search in both Google and MSDN search, I always get English links. I use English languaged browser as well, maybe this can cause it. For example Mozilla has: `Settings-->Content-->Languages` section which you can set preferred language option. I'm not %100 sure about this subject. I know that feel by the way, it's annoying.

Comment: @TimSchmelter My web browser right here (IE 11) appears to send `"ACCEPT": text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*` and `"ACCEPT-LANGUAGE": da-DK ` among others. That is "Danish (Denmark)". However, many websites do not offer Danish language versions, and then they fall back to English.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen & Soner: thanks to you both. I think that i can't avoid it and that it's not a browser setting(i'm using chrome). I think that it's related to google. I'm always getting localized results(determined by my IP) including german MSDN links. You can't turn off it easily. If i search at `www.google.co.uk` i'll see the english links. Maybe i will try the firefox/chrome extension [GoogleGlobal](https://www.redflymarketing.com/internet-marketing-tools/google-global/)

Comment: The extension works great. http://tinyurl.com/h3hclql

Comment: @TimSchmelter Great! Upvoted your comment so people can find it :)